# Why is the rate of effusion of a gas inversely proportional to (absolute) temperature?

Tags: physical-chemistry, gas-laws, gas-phase-chemistry

> **(iv) Rate of effusion of a gas:** The rate of passing of a gas through an orifice may be given as:
>
> $$r = \frac{PA}{\sqrt{2\pi RTm}}$$
>
> where
> $P = $ Partial pressure of the gas
> $A = $ Area of cross-section of the orifice
> $R = $ Gas constant
> $T = $ Absolute temperature
> $m = $ Molar mass of gas

I am unable to get two things straight:

1. Shouldn't higher temperatures mean higher energy for the molecules and therefore a greater rate of effusion?
2. Even if this is so, isn't absolute temperature the lowest temperature at which a gas can exist (zero volume) with a constant value corresponding to $\pu{-273.15 K}$?

Edit: I have resolved the first query, $P$ can be rewritten as $RT/V$ bringing the $\sqrt{T}$ term to the numerator.
I am however still confused with what is meant by absolute temperature.

Comment: Wrt question 1, [this gives an answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/119713/why-is-the-rate-inversely-proportional-to-the-square-root-of-temperature-in-grah). Wrt q2: you misunderstand the meaning of [absolute temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_temperature#Definition_of_thermodynamic_temperature).

Comment: But doesn't absolute temperature refer to absolute zero?

Comment: The absolute temperature scale *defines* an absolute zero which cannot be surpassed (unlike say Fahrenheit or Celsius, where negative temperatures are possible).

Comment: So absolute temperature just means temperature in the   Kelvin scale?

Comment: @JohnTony [Thermodynamic temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_temperature).

Comment: @JohnTony Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

The equation can be rewritten by substituting P = RT/V from the Ideal Gas Equation.
This gives us (A√RT/(V√2πm) showing that increase in temperature leads to increase in rate of effusion.
Absolute Temperature simply refers to the temperature on the Kelvin scale of absolute temperature.

Comment: `✓` is a check mark symbol that has nothing to do with a square root notation; this makes hard to read and parse your formulas. Please visit [this page](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [this page](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/) and [this one](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/) on how to format your future posts better with MathJax and Markdown, or just have a closer look at the corrections done to your question and use the markup as an example.